# Issue with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I've got problems running this code in PyCharm

```
import string
print string.ascii_lowercase
```

The code runs normally in Python IDLE (version 3.6), whereas in PyCharm it throws an error "No module named *'string'*"

Any ideas why it is going such way?

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

P.S. I've also tried to reinstall PyCharm, but the problem still remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your preferences in pycharm and go to the Project Interpreter. Make sure it is pointing to the same python interpreter that you want to use and hit ok.

Comment: Thx, I'll try in a minute.